# How do I find $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

I am

> given $y = (x_1,..., x_N)$ and $F  (y, x_1,..., x_N) = 0$.
>
> I need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$   in terms of the partials of $F$.

I have no idea at all after a lot of playing with it.

Comment: is $x=(x_1,\dots,x_N)$?

Comment: Do you mean $y$ is some function in $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$? If this is the case, then you need to use [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: I know that I have to use the implicit function theorem. Tecnically I was given $f(x) = f (x_1, ..., x_N) $.  The problem is I am unsure how to.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you mean $y = y(x_1,\dots,x_N)$. Then just differentiate $F$ w.r.t. $x_i$:
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}F(y,x) = F_y\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i} + F_{x_i}
$$
$$
  \Downarrow
$$
$$
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{F_{x_i}}{F_y}
$$
under the condition $F_y\neq 0$. More details are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).